# Get working code to see if access database is open

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I open an Access Database from Excel with click and VBA I want to check to see if Access is open on next click in the excel file to avoid opening another access file.

My Code:

```
Dim oApp As Object
    ' Path to Access database
    Dim LPath As String
    LPath = "C:\Users\kyle.overton1\Desktop\Access Database for Punch List.accdb"

    ' Exit if selection is more than one cell
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Validate if selected cell is in range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A23:A2000"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        ' Assign studentid value from current cell
        Init = Target.Value

        ' Call the open procedure with current cell value
        Call OpenAccess(Init)
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Sub OpenAccess(Init)
    Dim oApp As Object

    'Path to Access database
    Dim LPath As String
    LPath = "C:\Users\kyle.overton1\Desktop\Access Database for Punch List.accdb"

    'Open Access and make visible
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    oApp.Visible = True

    'Open Access database as defined by LPath variable
    oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase LPath
    oApp.DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_AllRecords"
    oApp.DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "Initiative_Nbr=" & Init
End Sub
```

This code works to open and filter to the correct file

My expected outcome would be to check if the database is open, if it is close it else continue

Comment: Use `GetObject` first. If Access is open, it will return that instance. If it's not open an error is returned (429). Use error handling to trap that error and use `CreateObject` for the new instance. There are tons and tons of code here and elsewhere that use this with Excel or Word, for example. Just search those two methods and the error number and you should turn up something you can use.

Comment: Thank you, yes the GetObject method worked:                                                                            'The file is open or another error occurred
    With GetObject(, "access.application").Quit
End With

Comment: I have another issue, I can not make any changes to the access database after it opens it closes with any click, any ideas?

Comment: Please ask a new question. You might want to read the site usage guidelines in the [help] to understand how Stack Overflow is designed. This is *not* a discussion forum...